# Store number in variable , add 1 then repeat

Tags: php, variables, content-management-system

I'm work on PHP CMS , almost done of it

I use the Material Design Lite pop-up share menu, this required a html `id` property

as ex. if I post 2 articles and share menu has same id number then, when user press on a one of them the 2 will appear

so I need PHP code that do this for me, I don't need a very difficult script

---

just need a script do this :

1 - make a variable contains id = 0

2 - add 1

3 - store the new value , id = 1

4 - repeat for every post

---

## I tried this code :

```
<?php
$id = 0;
echo $id += 1 ;
$id = $id ;
?>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Show some available code please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question with the code that you've tried.

Comment: @RobLang can you help me ?

Comment: And what is not working in your code? What is the current output and what do you expect to get? For me it seems like you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @Rizier123 the code is working 1 time , i mean if i reload the page this code will give me 2 if i reload the page 10 time output will still 2 i need the code to by someway dynamic to store number then when i output it again give me the last number + 1 the clean desc. 
i add a post with id 0 i want when i add the post 2 the id of this post change to 1 and post 3 id 2

Comment: I think you want to look at the `$_SESSION` array, so you can save values over page requests.

Comment: @Rizier123 yes i think this will work at first but it won't , i think session end in 30min (just thinking) i want some thing to store & update id every time no matter if it save id in a file , mysql table or whatever i just need it to save id forever to call it back then add 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want global counter you can save it to filesystem:

```
<?php
$idstr = file_get_contents("counter.txt");
$id = intval($idstr)+1;
file_put_contents("counter.txt", $id);
echo($id);
?>
```